# How to get co-ordinates of an image while zooming in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am working on a image displaying project.

The aim is to display the images that is fetched from the server.

We have to fetch different images while user zoom that images.

so I need to get the co ordinates of images while zooming and then that co ordinates have to passed to server and corresponding images have to be fetched from server.

So how can i get different cordinates of image while zooming and pass that cordinates.

Can anyone please help me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Hoping for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `bounds` of your image?

As you zoom in to a view the frame stays the same, but the bounds of the image changes. Try logging the bounds as you zoom and you'll see what I mean.

There is a difference between the frame and the bounds of the view.